# Returning the index of a string that is not within brackets

Tags: python

Suppose I have a string:

```
x = '[1.3].[1.2]'
```

How do I find the first index of `"."` that is not within the square brackets `([])`?

So for the above example the first `"."` is at index 5, it is not at index 2 since at index 2 the `"."` is within the square brackets.

I tried doing `x.index(".")` but that only returns the index of the first `"."` and that `"."` can be within brackets.

I also tried doing `x.index('].[') + 1` but that would fail for this example:

```
x = '[[1.3].[9.10]].[1.2.[4.[5.6]]]'
x.index('].[') + 1
6
```

Since the first `"."` that is not within brackets is at index 13

If anyone can help me out with this that would be really appreciated.

What this is is just you have two strings starting with '[' and ending with ']' and you connect them using '.', so

```
s1 = "[1.2]"
s2 = "[2.3]"

s1 + "." + s2
```

and basically I'm trying to get the index of the '.' after the strings are connected.

Comment: Are these supposed to be _nested lists_ that you're attempting to split?

Comment: Is this [*the actual problem you are trying to solve*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? It doesn’t really sound right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple “parser” for this:

```
def findRootIndexes (s):
    nested = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c == '[':
            nested += 1
        elif c == ']':
            nested -= 1
        elif c == '.' and nested == 0:
            yield i
```

```
>>> list(findRootIndexes('[1.3].[1.2]'))
[5]
>>> list(findRootIndexes('[[1.3].[9.10]].[1.2.[4.[5.6]]]'))
[14]
>>> list(findRootIndexes('[1.2].[3.4].[5.6]'))
[5, 11]
```

This is essentially a [pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) except that we don’t need to track different tokens but just the opening and closing bracket. So we just need to count how many open levels we still have.

---

If you want to take it even further, you can—as roippi suggested in the comments—add some syntax checking to prevent things like `[[1.2]]]`. Or you could also add some additional checks to make sure that an opening `[` is always preceded by a dot or another opening `[`. To do this, you could make it a one-look-behind parser. Something like this:

```
nested = 0
last = None
for i, c in enumerate(s):
    if c == '[':
        if last not in (None, '[', '.'):
            raise SyntaxError('Opening bracket must follow either `[` or `.`')
        nested += 1
    elif c == ']'
        if nested == 0:
            raise SyntaxError('Closing bracket for non-open group')
        nested -= 1
    elif c == '.' and nested == 0:
        yield i
    last = c
```

But of course, if you create that string yourself from components you know that are valid, such checks are not really necessary.

Comment: +1.  I would personally add in a `raise SyntaxError` in your decrementing block `if nested <= 0`

Answer (score 2):

In this solution we're counting the opening brackets. This is the easiest way I can imagine:

```
x = '[[1.3].[9.10]].[1.2.[4.[5.6]]]'

brackets = 0
pos = 0

for y in x:
    if y == '[': 
        brackets += 1
    elif y == ']':
        brackets -=1

    if brackets == 0:
        print(pos) # Find first occurence and break from the loop
        break

    pos += 1
```

Prints 13